# Flutter android licenses issue sdk compilation failed for mismatch java version

Tags: java, flutter, dart, java-8, sdk

Error: LinkageError occurred while loading main class com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/sdklib/tool/sdkmanager/SdkManagerCli has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 55.0
Android sdkmanager tool was found, but failed to run (/Users/ruban.dharmaraj/Library/Android/sdk/cmdline-tools/latest/bin/sdkmanager): "exited code
1".
Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK,
visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#android-setup for detailed instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Below steps can solve your issue

- Go to android studio
- open an project [empty project]
- click on File>Project Structure
- on left side click on sdk-location
- click on Gradle Settings
- on gradle projects options click on gradle JDK
- choose download JDK and select the downloaded JDK as Gradle JDK
- on terminal type "java -version" if its shows downloaded JDK version properly

Now type "flutter doctor --android-licenses" on terminal accept licenses by pressing Y
Now type "flutter doctor"
hurray! its working